# Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prop')

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I consistently found this error in Odoo 14 CE.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create Sale Quotation
2. Add line
3. Select Product
4. Fill Quantity
5. Quickly Fill Unit Price immediately after 4.

[image: Error]

This issue happens in every form. Just perform the quick actions repeatedly in very fast and continuous actions.

Comment: Have you tried page refresh? If it doesnt work, try to regenerate assets bundles under debug menu - be careful here and try it locally first!!!

Comment: Refresh the page is the workaround at the moment when it happens, but does not solve the problem. Please tell me how to regenerate assets bundle.

Comment: Enable developer mode, click on the bug icon in header (near activities watch icon) and click Regenerate Assets Bundles, but please try it locally first with database dump.

Comment: @DanielLagiň Tried it. The problem still persists.